# Why spectrogram from librosa library have twice the time duration of the actual audio track?

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram, librosa

I am using the following code to obtain Mel spectrogram from a recorded audio signal of about 30 s:

```
spectrogram =  librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=self.RawSamples,sr=self.SamplingFrequency, n_mels=128, fmax=8000)

if show:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(self.Spectrogram, ref=np.max), y_axis='mel', fmax=8000, x_axis='time')
    plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
    plt.title('Mel spectrogram')
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Obtained spectrogram: [Mel spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU0Pu.png)

Can you please explain me why the time axis depicts twice the time duration (it should be 30 s). What is going wrong with the code?

Comment: Are your raw samples from a stereo file, by any chance ?

Comment: Yes, it is a stereo wav file @PaulR

Comment: OK - so if you are treating the samples as a single channel then you will get twice the duration.

Comment: Do you know if there's any attribute to set when a call the spectrogram method from librosa in order to avoid this? Btw, thank you so much for answering, it's helping a lot @PaulR

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular library, but it should be fairly trivial to either extract a single (left or right) channel, or combine both channels into a single (mono) channel, and then process that.

Comment: Perhaps try [`librosa.core.to_mono`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.to_mono.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the sampling rate to `librosa.display.specshow` (sr=self.SamplingFrequency). If not it defaults to 20050 and if `self.SamplingFrequency` is a different value, it will display the wrong length.

Comment: I'm working on 90 seconds with 12000 sample rate. The spectrogram show the wrong time duration but the spectrogram itself is actually right, right?

Comment: Quite possible. But best to pass the right options to specshow to verify that things are as you expect

Comment: My code look like this  <br/>
`data, sr = librosa.load(file_name, sr=None, duration=90)`  <br/>
`D = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(librosa.stft(data)), ref=np.max)`  <br/>
`librosa.display.specshow(D, y_axis='linear', x_axis='time', sr=12000)`  <br/>
Am I passing the wrong?

Comment: That looks about right. But if you have an issue you should open a new question

Comment: Now the spectrogram shows the right duration but the wrong sample rate:(. Thank you anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

Your `librosa.display.spechow` should include the parameters: sampling rate `sr=<your_sampling_rate>` and also the hop size `hop_size=<your_hop_size>`. The default values for these parameters are 22050 and 512, respectively. Not setting them correctly leads to incorrect x-axis in the resulting spectrogram.

Reference: http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html